# Scatter with line segments

Tags: matlab

I really like `scatter()`'s ability to automatically color points based on some vector of values, I just want to add colored lines between the points.

The plot in question has time on x-axis, monte-carlo number on y-axis, and then some measured value as the color vector (e.g. number of cars seen in a video frame).

Basically, each point is an update in the system. So calling `scatter(time,monte_carlo_number,[],color_vec)` plots the points at which there is an update in the system, with color representing some value. This is great, but I would like to add line segments that connect these points, each segment matching the color specified by color_vec.

Basic working example

```matlab
% Create example data
data = table();
data.time        = randsample(1:100, 1000, true)';
data.mc          = randsample(1:50, 1000, true)'; % actual monte-carlo run number labels are sorted
data.color_value = randsample(1:10, 1000, true)';


% Create the scatter plot
scatter(data.time, data.mc, [] , data.color_value, 'filled')
colorbar('Ticks', unique(data.color_value))
% Always label your axes
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Monte-Carlo Run Number')
```

Below is a screen-shot of what this code might produce. If `color_value` is the number of cars seen in a video frame, we can see each time this value is updated via the points. However, it is easier for humans to read this plot if there were lines connecting each point to the next with the correct color. This demonstrates to the viewer that this value continues on in time until the next update. 
[image]

Comment: This sounds broadish for SO in my opinion. You'd need to do something along the lines of defining colour bins, e.g. 15-25, then find all points within said bin and define how to draw lines (all points to all points? Sequential? Delaunay?). Then plot all those things on top of one another (sounds like a visual mess to me).

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly that you wanted to connect all the blue(ish) points together (say 1 to 4), cyan (say 4 to 6) together, and so on?

Comment: I want each point to have a line of the same color moving forward in time, ending at the next point in time. Does that make sense?

Comment: in your example each "car" or color dot can appear more than once per time (I ran your code and saw it)  So what's the direction of time then? the question is not well defined.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I changed the number of samples to 100, and it is already quite a mess, so I don't think this is going to the viewer understand what's plotted.

```
% Create example data
data = table();
np = 100;
data.time        = randsample(1:100, np, true)';
data.mc          = randsample(1:50, np, true)'; % actual monte-carlo run number labels are sorted
data.color_value = randsample(1:10, np, true)';


vals = unique(data.color_value).';
cmap = parula(numel(vals));

colors = [];
for k = 1:numel(vals)
    ind = find(data.color_value == vals(k));
    data_sel{k} = sortrows(data(ind,:));
    colors(k,:) = cmap(k,:);
end


figure(1); clf;
% Create the scatter plot
scatter(data.time, data.mc, [] , data.color_value, 'filled')
hold on
for k = 1:numel(vals)
    plot(data_sel{k}.time, data_sel{k}.mc, 'Color',colors(k,:))
end
colorbar('Ticks', unique(data.color_value))
% Always label your axes
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Monte-Carlo Run Number')
```

[image]